# Libraries.android.view.InflateException:Binary XML file: Error inflating class android.view.View

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, binding

I am trying to wrap an Android native SDK into a Xamarin functionality. I have two .aar files, one depending on the other, which I bind each into two Android Binding projects. One of the binding projects has a reference to the DLL created for the other .aar file. I'm a bit confused about the generated classes, but I still can call the public methods from somewhere else.

This is what I want to do actually. the code from the native SDK that I'm calling creates a new activity, inherited from AppCompatActivity which is trying to set a custom layout and start on the screen. When the methods from my Android App finishes, the device screen became blank and the app is throwing :

> **libraries.android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.view.View**

This is the onCreate method which should be started. The worst part is that I'm not able to debug the SDK code (maybe someone know how to do that), I can't find the call stack to see where is happening the error and no relevant info in the logs.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle)
{
super.onCreate(paramBundle);

setFinishOnTouchOutside(false);

getWindow().addFlags(8192);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_myactivity);

this.e = new DeviceRotationManager(this, Rotation.NATIVE);

this.f = ((Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar));
setSupportActionBar(this.f);
....
}
```

What can be seen in the logs before crashing:

- 10-16 00:38:48.327 D/Mono (32438): Assembly Ref addref    DocVerif.Core[0x7f89f37d80] ->    Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat[0x7f953e2800]: 3
- 10-16 00:38:48.329 D/Mono (32438): Assembly Ref addref DocVerif.DV[0x7f89f37e80] ->    Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment[0x7f953e2180]: 4
- 10-16 00:38:48.329 D/Mono (32438): Assembly Ref addref DocVerif.Core[0x7f89f37d80] ->    Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment[0x7f953e2180]: 5
- 10-16 00:38:48.336 I/PhoneWindow(32438): [generateLayout] setColorNavigationBar => color=0x ff000001

Other info:

- Xamarin.Forms: v3.1.0.697729
- Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat : v27.0.2.1
- Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 : v27.0.2.1
- MonoAndroid90

Comment: Inflate refers to a XML layout, so please add the relevant parts of it here. Also providing the full stack trace would probably reveal more information of what is going on.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. It was actually a mismatching version of Android.Support.V7.AppCompat and the version of android libraries used for the SDK.